# Thread can't catch InterruptionException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have read the [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) on page 146, and I have coded the:

```
class RethroableTask implements Runnable{
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService cancelExec =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
   private Throwable t;
   public void run(){
       try{
            while(true){}
      }catch(Throwable t){
            this.t = t;
       }
   }

  public static void main(String[] args){
          RethroableTask task = new RethrowableTask();
          final Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
          taskThread.start();
          cancelExec.schedule(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                taskThread.interrupt();//i want taskThread can catch interruptedException
      }
     },1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

I want `taskThread` to catch `InterruptedException` as `Throwable`, and really the `taskThread` `isInterrupted` is `true`,but `taskThread` never catches it. Why?

I substitute `while(true){}` with

```
  try{
     Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);//a blocking method
     }catch(InterruptedException e){
      System.out.println("interruptedException");
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
```

it come in catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `InterruptedException` is only thrown when a thread is waiting on a blocking method call at the moment of interruption.

In all other situations, a thread must check its own interrupted status. If you want to test the class you've written, call a blocking method in your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike *stopping*, *interruption* is a cooperative mehanism: the `InterruptedException` must be explicitly thrown by some code after checking the *interrupted* flag of the current thread. This can be either a JDK method which declares to throw `InterruptedException` such as `Thread.sleep`, or your own code.

Instead of your empty loop, use

```
while (true) Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This will solve two problems at once:

1. it won't hog the CPU;
2. it will throw an `InterruptedException` when interrupted.

Comment: Great explanation of the cooperative underpinnings of thread interruption.